# Is there an efficient and quicker way to override compareTo() method used in TreeSet

Tags: java, compareto

I read a table containing six columns and pass into a `TreeSet` collection. It does work properly, however, I  am just curious if there is a more efficient way to over ride `compareTo()` method. The reason for asking this is that I will have extra sets with more columns and the way I do this seems to me so inefficient and time consuming. It is important to note that all the my class elements are integer.

Also, I have an extra question. Does one of the jobs of `compareTo()` method contain preventing duplication as `HashCode()` does in `HashMap()`?

Below I show how I define `compareTo()` method.

```
    public int compareTo(Network o) {
        int r = this.headNode > o.headNode? 1 : this.headNode < o.headNode ? -1   :  0;
        if(r==0) { r = this.headPeriod1 > o.headPeriod1? 1 :  this.headPeriod1 < o.headPeriod1? -1 : 0;
            if(r==0) {
                r = this.headPeriod2 > o.headPeriod2? 1 :  this.headPeriod2 < o.headPeriod2? -1 : 0;
                if(r==0) {
                    r = this.tailNode > o.tailNode? 1 :  this.tailNode < o. tailNode? -1 : 0;
                        if(r==0) {
                            r = this.tailPeriod1 > o.tailPeriod1 ? 1 :  this.tailPeriod1 < o.tailPeriod1 ? -1 : 0;
                                if(r==0) {
                                    r = this.tailPeriod2 > o.tailPeriod2 ? 1 :  this.tailPeriod2 < o.tailPeriod2 ? -1 : 0;
                                }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How about refactoring the code to use `if (r != 0) return r;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Comparator to do it more readable:

```
public class Test {

    int age;
    int money;
    int id;

    public Test(int age, int money, int id) {
        this.age = age;
        this.money = money;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Test t1 = new Test(25,200,3);
        Test t2 = new Test(30,50,5);
        Test t3 = new Test(15,90,9);

        Comparator<Test> comp = Comparator.<Test>comparingInt(x -> x.age)
                                            .thenComparingInt(x -> x.money)
                                            .thenComparingInt(x -> x.id);

        Set<Test> set = new TreeSet<>(comp); // Pass the comparator to the Treeset, TreeMap, etc., or use it inside of you Comparable.compareTo method.

        set.add(t1);
        set.add(t2);
        set.add(t3);

        System.out.println(set); // [Test{age=15, money=90, id=9}, Test{age=25, money=200, id=3}, Test{age=30, money=50, id=5}]
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{" + "age=" + age + ", money=" + money + ", id=" + id + '}';
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can use **Comparator.comparingInt**(x -> x.**headNode**)
                                            .thenComparingInt(x -> x.**headPeriod2**)
                                            .thenComparingInt(x -> x.**tailNode**)...

etc., to make it more meaningful.
You can keep adding more of those .thenComparingInt... as your class grows.
This will sort them by headNode, then by headPeriod2, then by tailNode, and so on.

(instead of x, use whatever name you would like for that varible, like (network -> network.headNode)

There are more static and instance methods in Comparator to create different Comparators that you can loop up.

**If you implement Comparable and want to use your Comparator inside of your compareTo method**, then put the Comparator created as an instance field and use the comparator inside comparteTo like this:

```
public class Test implements Comparable<Test>{

    int age;
    int money;
    int id;

    Comparator<Test> comp = Comparator.<Test>comparingInt(x -> x.age)
                                            .thenComparingInt(x -> x.money)
                                            .thenComparingInt(x -> x.id);

    public Test(int age, int money, int id) {
        this.age = age;
        this.money = money;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Test t1 = new Test(25,200,3);
        Test t2 = new Test(30,50,5);
        Test t3 = new Test(15,90,9);

        Set<Test> set = new TreeSet<>();

        set.add(t1);
        set.add(t2);
        set.add(t3);

        System.out.println(set); // [Test{age=15, money=90, id=9}, Test{age=25, money=200, id=3}, Test{age=30, money=50, id=5}]
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{" + "age=" + age + ", money=" + money + ", id=" + id + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Test o) {
        return comp.compare(this, o);
    }

}
```

**With Method Reference:**

```
public class Test implements Comparable<Test>{

    private int age;
    private int money;
    private int id;

    private final Comparator<Test> comp = Comparator.<Test>comparingInt(Test::getId)
                                            .thenComparingInt(Test::getMoney)
                                            .thenComparingInt(Test::getAge);

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Test t1 = new Test(25, 200, 3);
        Test t2 = new Test(30, 50, 5);
        Test t3 = new Test(15, 90, 9);

        Set<Test> set = new TreeSet<>();

        set.add(t1);
        set.add(t2);
        set.add(t3);

        System.out.println(set); // [Test{age=25, money=200, id=3}, Test{age=30, money=50, id=5}, Test{age=15, money=90, id=9}]
    }

    public Test(int age, int money, int id) {
        this.age = age;
        this.money = money;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getMoney() {
        return money;
    }

    public void setMoney(int money) {
        this.money = money;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Test o) {
        return comp.compare(this, o);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{" + "age=" + age + ", money=" + money + ", id=" + id + '}';
    } 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems pretty straight forward. In this scenario, I won't need to define compareTo() method, will I?

Comment: As I edited, you can keep using your compareTo method, with that little variable of using the comparator inside the compareTo. Like: @Override
    public int compareTo(Test o) {
        return comp.compare(this, o);
    }

Comment: Great, it works fine. We define compareTo() method just in case to avoid duplication, right?

Comment: If you add getters to your class you can then use method references in place of lambdas. So in Jeremy's example,`comparingInt(ClassName::getX).then...`

Comment: That is absolutely right WJS. The example that I made is not encapsulated, because I wanted to make it simple. But in real life, it's good idea to set the properties private and use getter methods and use the Method reference instead.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a little shorter/simpler:

```
   public int compareTo(Network o) {
        int r = this.headNode - o.headNode;
        if (r == 0) {
            r = this.headPeriod1 - o.headPeriod1;
            if (r == 0) {
                r = this.headPeriod2 - o.headPeriod2;
                if (r == 0) {
                    r = this.tailNode - o.tailNode;
                    if (r == 0) {
                        r = this.tailPeriod1 - o.tailPeriod1;
                        if (r == 0) {
                            r = this.tailPeriod2 - o.tailPeriod2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right, it definitely looks simpler. Would I get the same ordering still?

Comment: just caution with overflow - strongly advice using `Integer.compare(int,int)`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Do you mean something like if(Integer.compare(this.headPeriod2,o.headPeriod2) == true)

Comment: @ball_jan sure not, bad idea to use `==` between `int` and `boolean`.... more like `r = compare(this.headNode, o.headNode);` (after `import static java.lang.Integer.compare;`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger My bad! I thought `Integer.compare` returns a Boolean value. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

However you do it, I would strongly avoid subtracting values to get the < or > results of a comparator.  It can lead to errors and is a bad habit to get into. Check out the following:

```
      int val1 = -1223222022;
      int val2 = 2130200022;
      int result = compareTo(val1, val2);
      // This shows val1 > val2
      if (result < 0) {
         System.out.println(val1 + " < " + val2);
      }
      else if (result > 0) {
         System.out.println(val1 + " > " + val2);
      }

      val1 = 1234450392;
      val2 = -2022030049;
      result = compareTo(val1, val2);
      //this shows val2 < val2
      if (result < 0) {
         System.out.println(val1 + " < " + val2);
      }
      else if (result > 0) {
         System.out.println(val1 + " > " + val2);
      }
   }

   public static int compareTo(int a, int b) {
      return a - b;
   }
```

Just use the functional interface Comparable to tidy up your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I modified my code in the way Jeremy Then showed. I guess it is the safest option.